# AMD HD 8000 on UBUNTU 15.10

Tags: ati, fglrx

I changed to ubuntu recently and i'm having trouble to install my HD video card, i found at AMD website :

> fglrx-15.302

But when i try to install, it says it's not the supported version. Even if it says the opposite on AMD website, can someone help me to install it ? Or to find a solution so my video card work

Comment: AMD dropped legacy support for older chips on Linux, there is nothing you can do,I am sorry to say.

Comment: so, there is support for HD 2000-7000 but not for 8000 ? And can i go back to 15.04 or any older one? Or if i want to use HD i have to go back to Windows ?

Comment: There is not support for any of them I don't think, you can of course wait for an answer, but I faced this issue with a 7000, I could choose it on the site but the installer says it is not a supported version, there was no solution.

Comment: You could always see what the Additional Drivers app pulls up, but if what @markkirby says is true, it might not work.

Comment: Although, @markkirby, if that card is the Radeon HD 8000, it's pretty new (2013).

Comment: @Zacharee1 I was just looking in to this, here is an article I found to back up my claim, seems 8400 is the cut off point, no prop drivers ever. http://betanews.com/2015/11/24/amd-kills-gpu/

Comment: @markkirby "More modern cards?" wow... 2013 isn't that old.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I know right, I have an 7000 laptop from the same year I tried for hours, there was no way, intel HD works better than these AMD laptops now :(.

Comment: to be more specific Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330] (rev ff) (i think so at least :D)

Comment: As you mentioned going back to an older version of Ubuntu, I found a list of Ubuntu laptops that use this chip, they provide pre built images for the laptops with a driver but they are 12.04, take a look see if they match yours http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/component/pci/1002%3A6660/ If not there is a small, and I mean small chance there is a driver in the Ubuntu 12.04 additional drivers app, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this driver on Mint 17.3 with a Radeon HD 7450, so I don't think it's the device but rather the version of Ubuntu and AMD not updating their workspace often enough.

**fglrxinfo:**

> display: :0  screen: 0 OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices,
>   Inc. OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 7400 Series OpenGL version
>   string: 4.5.13416 Compatibility Profile Context 15.302

That said, kernel support only seems to go as far as around 4.2, and anything higher requires patching